# Does the rate limit graphql query in the Github API have a cost?

Tags: github, github-api

Lets say I have used up all my 5000 API requests per hour and want to know how many requests are remaining, will that query also have a cost and I will get an error saying rate limit exceeded or can I query that endpoint as many times as I want to.

I am talking about this graphql query

```
query {
  viewer {
    login
  }
  rateLimit {
    limit
    cost
    remaining
    resetAt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just the `rateLimit` alone costs nothing:

```graphql
{
  rateLimit {
    limit
    cost
    remaining
    resetAt
  }
}
```

But if you add any additionnal object such as the `viewer` in your example it will add costs as describe [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/#calculating-a-rate-limit-score-before-running-the-call)